# Who is Evermillion?

Tags: witch-craft-works

Evermillion was sealed inside Takamura's body/soul. She is arguably the most powerful witch, an endless source of mana, a deity, **_______**.

Tower Witches want to dominate / own her, workshop witches want to keep her locked.

Exactly WHAT or WHO is Evermillion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically just trashed my other answer, but you can always see it again in the edit history:  as of now she is still an unknown assailant.

### Background- Still unknown (partially):

> Evermillion is a huge mystery. Her origins, how she came to be sealed in Honoka, why she was sealed, and even what she actually is; are completely unknown (she referred to herself as a demon with Honoka, though it's possible she was being metaphorical). Sometime in the past she was sealed inside of Honoka Takamiya with a five layer barrier preventing her from escaping. She seems to have some history with Medusa.

### Who is she- Still unknown (partially):

> Evermillion (エヴァーミリオン?), fully named White Princess Evermillion
> (白姫エヴァーミリオン Shirohime Evamirion?), is an entity of unknown origin
> sealed inside Honoka Takamiya. She is addressed as the White Princess
> by various characters. A total of five seals were placed on her.

Source: http://witch-craft-works.wikia.com/wiki/Evermillion

Oh yeah, and theres scheduled to be an OVA as of 2015 per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_Craft_Works) too.

Comment: will there be a second season? :)

Comment: @Mindwin- Maybe, but looking at the mangas, there should be enough content for a season 2. This is a good link to look at though > http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1118399